# Variable name "value" is getting error in objective-c and swift combined project

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, compiler-errors, objective-c-swift-bridge

Created variable "value" in Objective-C file.

Then import this file in App-Bridging-Header.h file.

Then getting following error.

[image]

Before import in App-Bridging-Header.h file it's working.
After import in App-Bridging-Header.h file it's not working.

Comment: can you show this 6 lines code also? this error message is hiding what exactly you've written

Comment: @VincentJoy Question updated.

Comment: Pick a different name.